# What Linux command do I type to see my MySQL server load in real time?

Tags: linux, mysql, performance

What Linux command can I type where I can watch MySQL server load in real time?

BACKGROUND:
I can type 'top' and watch overall server load (just look at inverse of Idle % and consider it over a period of time). But I need to know how to see when MySQL is running into critical load and may run out of process handles or something like that unless I do something about it.

Comment: Collect metrics with Cacti or Munin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [innotop](https://code.google.com/p/innotop/), a `top` clone for MySQL. It is probably already in your package repositories.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend you [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/), a top clone for MySQL. It is also available in repositories of most common Linux distributions.

Comment: Hm. That doesn't seem to have been maintained in years.